# How to make my code interactive with ARGV in RUBY

Tags: ruby, argv

This is my PigLatin code and it works well but I need make it interactive with ARGV, it should be:

`$ ruby pig_latin.rb`  pig banana trash apple elephant
=> igpay ananabay ashtray appleway elephantway

```
def pig_latin(input)

        first_char = input[0,1]
        vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

        if vowels.include?(first_char)
            word = input[1..-1] + first_char + "way"
        else
            word = input[1..-1] + first_char + "ay"
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaned up version that's more Ruby-like:

```
def pig_latin(input)
  case (first_char = input[0,1])
  when /aeiou/i
    # Uses a simple regular expression to detect vowels
    input[1..-1] + first_char + "way"
  else
    input[1..-1] + first_char + "ay"
  end
end

# Transform the input arguments into their Pig Latin equivalents
# and combine into a single string by joining with spaces.
piglatined = ARGV.map do |arg|
  pig_latin(arg)
end.join(' ')

puts piglatined
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this at the end of the program:

```
if __FILE__ == $0 # if file is being run as script from command line
  puts(ARGV.map { |string| pig_latin(string) }.join(" "))
end
```

`ARGV` is an array of strings. You can use `map` to apply the `pig_latin` changes, and then print them on the same line, joined by `" "`

The benefit of using `if __FILE__ == $0` is that it doesn't require your program to use ARGV. E.g. you could still use it with `require`.

Comment: Thanks @maxpleaner